# Unicons are not Showing Even After Linking them

Tags: html, css

This is the code `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unicons.iconscout.com/release/v3.0.1/css/unicons.css">`

As you have see I have linked it correctly in index.html under the  part.
Do I have to add github plugin in atom to use it or any other way to do it?

```
<nav>
    <div class="container inner">
        <div class="logo">
            <i class="uil uil-cell"></i>
   

     Rohit's CV
        </div>
        <div>
            <button>
                <i class="uil uil-print"></i>
                Print
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

I even have use i class properly.
I got the icons from here:https://github.com/Iconscout/unicons

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try downgrading version as

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unicons.iconscout.com/release/v2.1.6/css/unicons.css">`

Seems like font icons in version 3.0.1 is currently having issues

Answer (score 1):

if you visit the link to your stylesheet it appears to be taken offline..

https://unicons.iconscout.com/release/v3.0.1/css/unicons.css

here is the active one:

https://unicons.iconscout.com/release/v3.0.6/css/solid.css

As you can see they have created a paid and free version. This will result in a couple of name changes and/or unusable icons.

But as you can see it does work. I have made a snippet so you can see.

```css
i {
  font-size: 100px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unicons.iconscout.com/release/v3.0.6/css/solid.css">  
<i class="uis uis-airplay"></i>
```

Comment: So what should I do?

Comment: search for icons that are available i guess.. I myself use the free version of font awesome.

Comment: Thanks a lot! And how can I see what icons are available?

Comment: I just did a quick search on google and found this. https://iconscout.com/unicons/getting-started/solid

Here you can find the active stylesheet to use.

Comment: Thanks a lot! RaRa Ritalin! You are the kindest person I have met here!

Comment: The v3.0.6 also did not work but '<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unicons.iconscout.com/release/v2.1.0/css/unicons.css">' but this worked :)

Comment: It is working. But since they made a paid and free version they have changed the names of the icons. Search the website and you see the free icons and what names you should use.